# Mongodb how can I query a subset of an array for a specific document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to run a query to select specific documents.  Then on each document, open up an array of sub documents and run a query to filter those sub docs.

Example:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectID(23412351346435),
  "list" : [
    {date: ISODate(2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z), name: "Jan 12"},
    {date: ISODate(2015-01-13T00:00:00.000Z), name: "Jan 13"},
    {date: ISODate(2015-01-14T00:00:00.000Z), name: "Jan 14"}
  ]
}
```

I'm guessing I can do something with Mongo's `aggregate` function.  I have been able to match the documents I want, but how can I get a sub query going on the array?  I tried using `$elemMatch` but that only returns the first item in the array that matches the date range.

To be clear when I query for `ObjectID(23412351346435)` and Date range 2015-01-12 to 2015-01-13 I want it to return this;

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectID(23412351346435),
   "list" : [
        {date: ISODate(2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z), name: "Jan 12"},
        {date: ISODate(2015-01-13T00:00:00.000Z), name: "Jan 13"}
   ]
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get the results you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, you can use `aggregation` to get the results you are looking for. The steps you need in your [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) are the following.

1. [Match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the documents you want. (I've done that here by `_id`).
2. [Unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `list` array.
3. Match the dates you are looking for using a range query.
4. [Group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the documents back by `_id`.

Your query should look something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([   
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("54ef8b0acfb269d664de0b48")} },
    { "$unwind": "$list" },
    { "$match": {
        "list.date": { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
                       $lte: ISODate("2015-01-13T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "list": { "$push": { "date": "$list.date", "name": "$list.name" }}
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Ahh, the unwind + group is what I was looking for.  Didn't think to use group to put them back together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator. It allows you to take an array in a document, and clone that document with each of the array elements. Then you can match on the field. If necessary, you can use $group to wind the document back up.

```
[
    {$match:{...}},
    {$unwind:"myfield"},
    {$match:{"myfield.name":"Jan 12"}},
    {$group:{ _id:"$id", "myfield":{$push:"$myfield"} }}
]
```

Note that $unwind is slow for large sets of documents, and combinatoric for multiple arrays. It is the only option you really have for Mongo 2.4.x though. You might be better served by rearranging your data so that you do not have arrays.